# How do I remove any data from a LiveUSB with data persistence?

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, live-cd

I have miss-configured my LiveUSB installation and now when I run boot from it I get an error.

How can I erase LiveUSB data? Can it be done from the booting LiveUSB menu?

For some weird reason LiveCD remembers the state between runs. That is a very cool feature, but I need to reset all that data.

I have problem with MBR on my hard drive and I want to install Ubuntu, however I can't since booting from CD has now its own problems.

When I run the LiveUSB I get an error right away. I don't have option to install Ubuntu. After waiting 20 minutes I get an option to log in into Ubuntu.

Comment: Guessing creating a new USB stick with Ubuntu from another computer is not an option?

Comment: `After waiting 20 minutes I get an option to log in into Ubuntu.`. Can you log in? There is an option to Install Ubuntu when you are in live session. And I don't really get what data are you trying to clear and what for?

Comment: Pavel : livecd data. there is no option to login or install ubuntu. because there are errors. I will try to create new usb stick with ubuntu, but now its not an option (I only have one computer at home)

Answer (score 0):

All your changed data is stored in a file/partition named/labeled "casper-rw".  You should be able to mount either one, and delete/add/change things.  Not everything you add can be seen, for instance /etc/fstab, but most things can.  You can even change the boot commands on your boot media -- edit syslinux/txt.cfg  and remove the "persistent" word on the append line (in several places).